# Event for after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

After button is clicked I call one procedure.

After the procedure's return based on return code i need to redirect to a page.

The problem is that if an exception raises in the procedure on after submit is called before that exception.

So I need an event after calling procedure and exception based on exception I need to check in that javascript function. Tell me any event which run after procedure exception.

```
onAfterSubmit: function (){
    alert('on before call');
    var error=$('#errormsg').text().trim();//Any exception it print in this panel 

    alert('error=>'+error); 

    if (error!="") {            
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location.href="../jsp/passwordresetack.jsp";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?? Any jsfiddle??

Comment: @User..Please post your code for better understanding. this way its hard to find out where you are going wrong or what you were missing?

Comment: Code you tried yet....